# Line Overwriting int txt file php

Tags: php, file-handling, file-writing

I am trying to append text from an array to the end of a user selected line of a file.  `Intro to PHP$$Prog-6218$$7
Java 3$$Prog-2743$$4$$
Linux$$Prog-5490$$8$$
Online Marketing$$Buis-5567$$10$$
Marketing History$$Buis-2247$$9$$
World Impact of Computing$$Elect-7785$$5$$`

How can I cannot figure out how to overwrite any of the lines line

Comment: looks like some one needs to learn how to use a real data base

Comment: Right now I am just a beginner trying to do some file handling in a language I am not familiar in.  So far I can use a database only java but I am trying

Comment: it is really less code and easier than flat files,

Comment: I know it can be less code using a DB_Access class but for now I am doing the basics that yes does take longer but soon I will restart the whole project and condense.

Comment: you want to add to a  particular line, you must read the whole thing, find the line edit and write the whole thing back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sketch of how you'd do it:

```
$fname = "books.txt";
$insertLine = 3;
$newLine = "Code Complete$$Prog-1234$$9$$";

// Read lines from file into array and split by new lines
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($fname));

// Insert your new line/book details
array_splice($lines, $insertLine, 0, $newLine);

// Glue old + our new line back into array using
// new line as element separator and write back to file
file_put_contents($fname, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

I noticed your lines are delimited by `$$`. You may want to look into [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) and [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).